# Scalelite Load balancer giving error when trying to add new servers

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ruby, vultr

I have two stand alone Vms in vultr running on Ubuntu 18.04 and on top of it I have installed Bigbluebutton server configs and a Greenlight frontend.
I have configured another server for scalelite on vultr itself and installed Postgres and redis on it and deployed scalelite docker containers on it. My scalalite load balancer secret and the bigbluebutton servers' secret are the same.

I have followed everything as per [this document](https://github.com/blindsidenetworks/scalelite#before-you-begin).

When I try to add servers using the command

```
./bin/rake servers:add[url,secret,loadMultiplier]

url: my bigbluebutton server url
secret: the one that is same as scalelite Lb
multiplier :1
```

It's giving me an error saying :

```
"bash: ./bin/rake: No such file or directory"
```

`ruby -v`:

```
ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
```

I installed `rake` using package manager:

```
sudo apt-get install rake
```

Again it shows no file or directory named .bin.

Can somebody help me figure out this?

Comment: Does just `rake servers:add ...` work?

Comment: @shearn89 when I try the command 'docker exec -it scalelite-api /bin/sh' it's showing that no such container scalelite-api and './bin/rake servers' command is giving me ./bin/rake: No such file or directory.

Comment: Okay, so you're not running it as a container and there's no `./bin` folder. Like I said, what happens if you run the `rake` command without the `./bin/`?